# Непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "ResolvePackageAssets"

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

Возникла ошибка во время компиляции .NET 6.0 проекта в Visual Studio. Ошибка гласит: Непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "ResolvePackageAssets". Unable to find fallback package folder 'H:\Coding\Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.

Полный лог ошибки:

```
Ошибка  MSB4018 непредвиденная ошибка при выполнении задачи "ResolvePackageAssets".
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'H:\Coding\Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
   в NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
   в Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   в Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()  ConsoleApp1 C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets    267
```

Visual Studio пытается обратиться к пути 'H:\Coding\Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'. Однако такого пути больше нет на моей системе, мне нужно было перенести систему с одного диска на другой и диск на котором был Visual Studio переименовался с H на F.

Сейчас требуемая папка находится на пути 'F:\Coding\Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
Однако Visual Stuido все еще пытается обратится по старому пути.

Я пытался полностью переустанавливать Visual Studio, выполнять "Восстановление" Visual Studio, искал возможно ли изменить путь в реестре, искал путь в параметрах Visual Studio, искал где можно изменить путь, ничего не помогло.

Возможно ли решить это?

Answer (score 0):

Тут все просто, есть такое хранилище сборок называется GAC (Global Assembly Cache)
найдите в нем *NuGet*
и удалите все вхождения, физический путь к папке
**%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly**